# MapView is only refreshing when it's touched

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I have a MapView in a fragment and I want to show the user's current location.
My problem is that it's only refreshed (in layers, first the terrain, then the
name of the streets...) when the MapView is touched. It shows a front camera
preview also. Here's my code.
The Fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/otherRelative"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/otherRelative" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/camPreview"
            android:layout_width="163dp"
            android:layout_height="211dp" >

        </FrameLayout>

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.08"
            app:cameraZoom="15"
            map:mapType="normal" >
        </com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the fragment code

```
public class MarcacionFragment extends Fragment {
    // Graphics
    private Camera mCam;
    private MirrorView mCamPreview;
    private FrameLayout mPreviewLayout;
    private MapView ViewMap;
    private GoogleMap map;

    // Size of the camera preview
    private int size = 500;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    private int mCameraId = 0;
    private CameraUpdate cameraUpdate;

    public MarcacionFragment() {
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // retain this fragment
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mCam == null && mPreviewLayout != null) {
            mPreviewLayout.removeAllViews();
            startCameraInLayout(mPreviewLayout, mCameraId, getView());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (mCam != null) {
            mCam.release();
            mCam = null;
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.marcacion_layout, container, false);
        mCameraId = findFirstFrontFacingCamera();
        mPreviewLayout = (FrameLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.camPreview);
        ViewMap = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        ViewMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        map = ViewMap.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mPreviewLayout.removeAllViews();
        startCameraInLayout(mPreviewLayout, mCameraId, rootView);
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

        // Start GPS service
        gps = new GPSTracker(rootView.getContext());
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(gps.getLatitude(), gps.getLongitude());
            cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);

            map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).draggable(true));
            ViewMap.setClickable(false);
        } else {
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }
        ViewMap.invalidate();
        return rootView;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private int findFirstFrontFacingCamera() {
        int foundId = -1;
        int numCams = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camId = 0; camId < numCams; camId++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camId, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                foundId = camId;
                break;
            }
        }
        return foundId;
    }

    private void startCameraInLayout(FrameLayout layout, int cameraId, View rootView) {
        mCam = Camera.open(cameraId);
        if (mCam != null) {
            mCamPreview = new MirrorView(rootView.getContext(), mCam);
            mCamPreview.getHolder().setFixedSize(size, (size / 4) * 3);
            mCamPreview.setCameraDisplayOrientationAndSize(getActivity(), cameraId);
            layout.addView(mCamPreview);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I refresh the mapView without touching it?

Comment: It works fine in litemode, but I need zoom in/out the map